# Does changing the icon of the lollipop farm tree have any effect?

Tags: candy-box

When clicking on the lollipop tree on the lollipop farm, the icon changes. The possible values, when cycled, are `*`, `cnd`, `!`, `+`, `?`, `/|\`, and `~`.

Does this have any in game effect other than some basic customization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is purely cosmetic...